# Is there any way to access some global values among react native projects, with or without expo?

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, gradle

I want one global configurations file that could be stored in either constants.js file where it looks like

```
    export const targetSdkVersion = 29
    export const versionCode= 79
    export const versionName= 1.34.4`
```

& then accessing these variables inside build.gradle(android/app).
not `export` only any keyword/any method that allows variables declared in JS files to be readable by build.gradle fil.

Or any other way using which I can specify a file to be read by both Source Level JS & build.gradle. Which will ease me reflecting change at everywhere just by changing value at one place.

Comment: Kidnly check [react-native-config](https://github.com/luggit/react-native-config) it does provide to read values from env in android or ios.

Comment: Thanks but whole things are maintained over package level & needs configuration, I needed to know about if I can just access project level variables inside the whole project wherever I needed that

Comment: No i don't think it will be possible without using package.